My MACD indicator and back-test are not working
type here
I have two indicator SMA and MACD
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def SMA(p,window=10,signal_type='long'):
    # p - price used for SMA, the nxm DataFrame
    # window - look-back window size
    # signal_type - long (default), short, or both (not recommended)
    signal = pd.DataFrame(index=p.index,columns=p.columns)
    sma = pd.DataFrame(index=p.index,columns=p.columns)
    for i in window+np.arange(p.shape[1]-window):
        #loop each column for all dates
        sma.iloc[:,i] = np.mean(p.iloc[:,(i-window):(i-1)],axis=1)
    if signal_type=='long':
        signal = (sma<p)*1 #1 for holding a long position
    elif signal_type=='short':
        signal = (sma>p)*(-1) #-1 for holding a short position
    elif signal_type=='both':
        signal = (sma<p)*1+(sma>p)*(-1)
    signal.iloc[:,-1]=0 #always close position at the market close
    # return sma and the signal DataFrames, both nxm
    return sma, signal
    
##########

def MACD(p, short_window=12, long_window=26, signal_type='long'):
    # p - price used for MACD, the nxm DataFrame
    # short_window - short-term EMA window size, default is 12
    # long_window - long-term EMA window size, default is 26
    # signal_type - long (default), short
    
    signal = pd.DataFrame(index=p.index, columns=p.columns)
    macd = pd.DataFrame(index=p.index, columns=p.columns)
    
    for i in long_window+np.arange(p.shape[1]-long_window):
        # Calculate short-term EMA and long-term EMA
        short_ema = p.iloc[:,(i-short_window+1):i].ewm(span=short_window).mean()
        long_ema = p.iloc[:,(i-long_window+1):i].ewm(span=long_window).mean()
        macd.iloc[:,i] = short_ema - long_ema
    
    if signal_type=='long':
        signal = (macd > 0)*1 #1 for holding a long position
    elif signal_type=='short':
        signal = (macd < 0)*(-1) #-1 for holding a short position
    elif signal_type=='both':
        signal = (macd > 0)*1 + (macd < 0)*(-1)
    
    signal.iloc[:,-1]=0 #always close position at the market close

    # return macd and the signal DataFrames, both nxm
    return macd, signal 


The back-test for SMA goes well, but when I tried to do the same with MACD, the value and signal I get are all nan and 0.
these are my back test code,

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import technical_indicator as tech
import preanalysis as pre

import os
os.getcwd() #know your work directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/4399l/OneDrive - Cardiff University/Trading, market design and application/coursework 2') #set your work directory, e.g. C:/Users/c0000000

''' Define functions for backtest analysis '''
def cntTrades(signal):
    #find the number of trades in each day
    change_position = signal.copy().diff(axis=1)
    if (np.sum(signal.values>0)>0) and (np.sum(signal.values<0)==0):
        #long only strategy
        return np.sum(change_position>0,axis=1)
    if (np.sum(signal.values<0)>0) and (np.sum(signal.values>0)==0):
        #short only strategy
        return np.sum(change_position<0,axis=1)

    return 

def calTotRet(p,signal):
    # p - transaction price
    # signal - position holding signal
    #find the number of trades in each day
    change_position = signal.copy().diff(axis=1)
    ret = np.zeros(p.shape[0])
    if (np.sum(signal.values>0)>0) and (np.sum(signal.values<0)==0):
        #long only strategy
        ind_in = np.where((change_position==1).values)
        ind_out = np.where((change_position==-1).values)
        for i in np.arange(p.shape[0]):
            p_in=p.values[i,ind_in[1][ind_in[0]==i]]
            p_out=p.values[i,ind_out[1][ind_out[0]==i]]
            ret[i] = np.sum(np.log(p_out/p_in))
        return ret
    if (np.sum(signal.values<0)>0) and (np.sum(signal.values>0)==0):
        #short only strategy
        ind_in = np.where((change_position==-1).values)
        ind_out = np.where((change_position==1).values)
        for i in np.arange(p.shape[0]):
            p_in=p.values[i,ind_in[1][ind_in[0]==i]]
            p_out=p.values[i,ind_out[1][ind_out[0]==i]]
            ret[i] = np.sum(np.log(p_out/p_in))
        return ret

    return ret

file_name = 'AMD_1m.csv' 
dat = pd.read_csv(file_name,parse_dates=['Datetime'],index_col='Datetime')
trans_dat = pre.transform(dat) 
trans_dat = trans_dat.astype('float') 
fixed_trans_dat = pre.fill_missing_dat(trans_dat)

holding = 'long' #a long-only strategy
short_window = 12 #short-term EMA window size
long_window = 26 #long-term EMA window size
macd_value, macd_signal = tech.MACD(fixed_trans_dat, short_window=short_window, long_window=long_window ,signal_type=holding)
print(macd_signal.head())
# analysis table for RSI
cols = ['Num.Obs.', 'Num.Trade', 'Tot.Ret', 'Std.Ret', 'Tot.PnL', 'Win.Ratio'] 

backtest_rs_2 = pd.DataFrame(index = fixed_trans_dat.index, columns=cols)
backtest_rs_2['Num.Obs.'] = np.sum(~np.isnan(trans_dat),axis=1)
backtest_rs_2['Num.Trade'] = cntTrades(macd_signal)
backtest_rs_2['Tot.Ret'] = calTotRet(fixed_trans_dat,macd_signal)
backtest_rs_2['Std.Ret'] = backtest_rs_2['Tot.Ret'].std()
backtest_rs_2['Tot.PnL'] = backtest_rs_2['Tot.Ret'].sum()
backtest_rs_2['Win.Ratio'] = np.where(backtest_rs_2['Num.Trade'] != 0, (backtest_rs_2['Tot.Ret'] > 0).sum() / backtest_rs_2['Num.Trade'], 0)


I tried with a new MACD indicator and checked my data but it still does the same, the macd value and macd signal are all blank and the analysis table only have num.obs and the rest are blank.
